# Deployed Rails app still seeing nginx splash page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I've just set up my first Digital Ocean VPS and managed to deploy my Rails app by following this guide: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

Unfortunatley I am still seeing the nginx splash page and hoep you guys can help me fix this?

In the nginx error log I am seeing this:

> [ 2016-04-20 14:48:15.4541 31875/7f70762f57c0 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 31875
>   2016/04/21 14:58:58 [emerg] 1721#0: "listen" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:27

My nginx conf looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name dev.myapp.co.uk;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

I obviously have changed "myapp" to my correct domain and app name as appropriate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems like you are having two nginx configuration files inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and both of them have the same `listen 80 default_server;` line.

Comment: Yes, it's a symlink to default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Comment: Please make sure you have only one conf file with `listen 80` line . Try moving the conf with `.save` extension out of the sites-enabled directory.

Comment: Perfect Thanks!  What was the .save file all about then?

Comment: Configuration file with `.save` extension must be created by the nano editor you used to edit the configuration file. [More here](http://askubuntu.com/a/601989).

You could mark the answer as accepted if it helped. Thanks.